# Можно ли в RecyclerView увеличить число элементов, которые не будут использованы повторно?

Tags: java, android

Пытаюсь сделать горизонтальный список, в котором элементы по клику меняют цвет.

Столкнулся с тем, что когда меняется цвет у первого элемента, то меняет цвет и 7-й, 13-й, 19-й и т.д.

В принципе, большой список не нужен, хватило бы и 10-15 элементов.

Или как-то привязать элементы к позиции?

```
public class ContactAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactAdapter.ContactViewHolder> {

private List<ContactInfo> contactList;

boolean button = false;

public ContactAdapter(List<ContactInfo> contactList) {

    this.contactList = contactList;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {

    return contactList.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ContactViewHolder contactViewHolder, int i) {
    ContactInfo ci = contactList.get(i);

    contactViewHolder.vName.setText(ci.name);
    contactViewHolder.vSurname.setText(ci.surname);

    //contactViewHolder.butto.setText(ci.name);
    //contactViewHolder.vEmail.setText(ci.email);
    //contactViewHolder.vTitle.setText(ci.name);

}

@Override
public ContactViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_layout, viewGroup, false);

    return new ContactViewHolder(itemView);

}

public  class ContactViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener, View.OnLongClickListener  {

    protected TextView vName;
    protected TextView vSurname;
    protected Button butto;
    protected TextView vEmail;
    protected TextView vTitle;

    public ContactViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        vName =  (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.time);
        vSurname = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.days);
        butto = (Button)  v.findViewById(R.id.but);

        //vEmail = (TextView)  v.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);
       // vTitle = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title);

        butto.setOnClickListener(this);
        butto.setOnLongClickListener(this);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);
        v.setOnLongClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(butto)) {
            if (!button) {
                butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.active_y);
            }
            else {
                butto.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.inactive_y);
            }
            button = !button;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
        if (v.equals(butto)) {
            removeAt(getPosition());
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void removeAt(int position) {
        contactList.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
            notifyItemRangeChanged(getPosition(), contactList.size());
    }

}}
```

Comment: Похоже, [XY Problem](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-x-y-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-xy-problem)

Comment: Добавление choice mode для [RecyclerView](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/recyclerview-part-2-choice-modes/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RecyclerView` имеет вспомогательный класс `Recycler` для управления переиспользованием айтемов.
Данный класс включает метод [`setViewCacheSize()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler.html#setViewCacheSize(int)), позволяющий указать, сколько айтемов должно сохранятся перед переиспользованием, но это все же не полноценное решение вашей проблемы.

С моей точки зрения, наиболее правильным решением будет добавить служебный массив для хранения состояний (для вашего случая хватит булевых значений, но в общем случае массив целочисленных значений, если цветов несколько) с размером, аналогичным размеру списка моделей. Этот массив будет хранить отметки о том, какой цвет использовать для определенного айтема.

Номер элемента в массиве будет соответствовать номеру айтема. По клику,кроме изменения цвета, в случае булевых значений, нужно так же инвертировать состояния элемента в массиве (либо записывать значение, если цветов несколько).
В методе `onBindViewHolder` нужно проверять, какое состояние установлено для текущего элемента и присваивать соответствующий цвет ( обязательно для обоих состояний, иначе будут накладки при переиспользовании).

Кроме того, хотя класс `ViewHolder` имеет методы для получения текущей позиции в адаптере (`getAdapterPosition()` и `getLayoutPosition()`) для упрощения кода, я бы перенес слушатель и обработку кликов прямо в адаптер.

Answer (score 0):

По хорошему нужно сохранять информацию а цвете вашей модели. Например вы передаете `contactList` типа `ContactInfo` - сделайте чтобы `ContactInfo` мог хранить информацию о цвете когда по нему кликнули, и соответственным образом их отображайте.