# Не сохраняются введенные в EditText значения в ListView

Tags: java, android

У меня в `ListView` есть 30 элементов. Если в нулевой элементе я что-то напишу, то при пролистывании вниз эти данные могут оказаться вообще внизу, или даже на месте 4 12 15 28.

Поэтому я решил, что будет лучше, если в `ListView` отключить как-то пересоздание компонентов.

Или в `EditText` поймать тот момент, когда человек теряет фокус, чтобы я сохранил данные в файл, а после - считал их.

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.main_list, null);
    }
    EditText editText = (EditText)convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
    editText.setHint("asdsadad");
    // SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    // sharedPreferences.getString("pos" + position, "");
    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Вы очевидно неправильно используете механизм переиспользования элементов. Покажите в каком месте вы меняете значение вью, кое потом показывается в других элементах.

Comment: Кстати еще одна вещь странная. Если активрировать EditText и пролистывать ListView то где - то на 10 элемиенте фокус встанет на 10 элемент. Чо за?

Comment: Используйте в вашем Адаптере паттерн ViewHolder, либо вместо ListView используйте недавно появившийся компонент RecycleView

Comment: RecycleView лучше?
А там точно заработает эта фишка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так как айтемы многократно переиспользуются, вам необходимо позаботиться о восстановлении состояния конкретного айтема в определенной позиции, для этого  вам нужно сохранять ввод из `EditText`-ов в отдельное хранилище, которое будет привязано к позициям в списке и затем использовать эти данные при (пере-)создании айтема. Необходимо не только восстанавливать ввод, но и принудительно очищать `EditText`, если ввода в нем не было. Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/436775/177345) для более подробного решения.

Для извлечения данных из айтемов списка в `EditText` при потере фокуса смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/446113/%D0%98%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%87%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%B2-edittext-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B8%D0%B7-listview/446178#446178) (пункт2).

Что вы будете использовать, `ListView` или `RecyclerView` не имеет особого значения. Так же как для решения вашей проблемы не подойдет и паттерн `ViewHolder` (хотя его использование и очень рекомендуется), который хранит только ссылки на виджеты (исключает многократный вызов метода `findViewById()`), а не содержимое этих виджетов.