# Сменить изображение ListView onItemClick

Tags: java, android, listview

Нужно по нажатию на item в ListView сменить Image (пометить как просмотренную запись).
Использую такой код:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
           for (int i = 0; i <= lv.getCount(); i++) {
                //.getAdapter().getCount()
                //.getCount();
                if (position == i) {

                    if (dbHandler.getDeliveredShipping(_id) == true) {
                        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberVisited_image)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check_all);
                    } else if (dbHandler.getDeliveredShipping(_id) == false) {
                        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21908022/change-image-of-imageview-onitemclicklistener-of-listview-in-android
                        ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.subscriberVisited_image)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_check);
                        //lv.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                    }
                }
            }
});
```

Щелкнул по одному item картинка (галка) меняется также меняется на ниже стоящем item (пунктов примерно 7 в низ). Делал debug, нет перескоков на нижний item.
Как такое происходит?

[image: фото]

Адаптер:

```
  SimpleAdapter adapter;
  lv = getListView();
  ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> contactList;
  contactList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Dismiss the progress dialog
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
        /**
         * Updating parsed JSON data into ListView
         //             * */
        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                MainActivity.this,
                contactList,
                R.layout.list_item,
                new String[]{TAG_ID, TAG_SUBSCRIBER_NAME, TAG_NEWSPAPER_MNEMONIK_NAME,
                        TAG_NUMBER_PUBLICATION, TAG_PHONE1},
                new int[]{R.id.idShipping, R.id.subscriberName, R.id.newspaperName,
                        R.id.newspaperPubNumber, R.id.subscriberTelNumber}
        );
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Покажите код адаптера, сдается мне вы там переиспользование ячеек никак не предусмотрели.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Как понять не предусмотрел переиспользование ячеек?

Comment: Тема переиспользования айтемов в списке обсуждалась на этом ресурсе уже много раз, воспользуйтесь поиском для решения вашей проблемы

Comment: cмотрите, например, [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460790/177345)

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: RecycleView с какой версии Android API начал работать? Минимальная версия API моего приложения 11.

Comment: Как еще можно уведомить пользователя что item он уже посещал? Кто какими методами пользуется?

Answer (score 1):

Боюсь SimpleAdapter не рассчитан на то что бы использоваться с ячейками в которых вы что то ещё и сами кодом меняете, проблема в том что когда ячейка в который вы что то поменяли проскроливается за экран, то она переиспользуется для отображения новой ячейки которая появится на экране. При этом изменяются только данные для вьюх, чьи id вы перечисляете в массиве который отправляете последним параметром в конструктор SimpleAdapter. Таким образом если вы там что то изменили сами, то эти изменения останутся и для новой ячейки. Так что вам придется либо унаследоваться от SimpleAdapter, либо от BaseAdapter и реализовать там хранение и применение изменившихся состояний.

Comment: Какой адаптер подойдет, вернее какой использовать лучше?

Comment: Ну если наследоваться от SimpleAdapter, то полагаю дописывать самому придется меньше всего.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду унаследовать main активити, она у меня унаследована так  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity

Comment: Я имею в виду создать свой класс адаптера унаследованный от SimpleAdapter, реализовать в нем то что я выше описал и использовать его а не SimpleAdapter.