# Почему при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView срабатывает несколько OnClick методов?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Почему при нажатии на элемент RecyclerView срабатывает несколько OnClick методов, т.е. меняется бэкграунд у нескольких элементов?

Разметка:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
android:id="@+id/calculator_activity_what_to_exchange_horizontal_recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/white" />
```

Класс:

```
mFromRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.calculator_activity__horizontal_recycler_view);
mFromAdapter = new CalculatorHorizontalAdapter();
mFromRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
mFromRecyclerView.setAdapter(mFromAdapter);
mFromAdapter.setCourseArray(courseArray);
mFromAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Адаптер:

```
public class CalculatorHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalculatorHorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private Course[] courseArray;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView ShortTv;
        public TextView LongTv;
        public TextView Long2Tv;
        public LinearLayout holderLayout;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ShortTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_calculator_currency_short_tv);
            holderLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_calculator_currency_ll);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.item_calculator_currency, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        if (courseArray[position].currencyBuy != null)
            holder.ShortTv.setText(setOfCourses.get(position));

        holder.holderLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.holderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0f67c0"));

            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return courseArray.length;
    }
    public CalculatorHorizontalAdapter(Course[] courseArray) {
        this.courseArray = courseArray;
    }
    public CalculatorHorizontalAdapter() {

    }
    public void setCourseArray(Course[] courseArray) {
        this.courseArray = courseArray;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вчера столкнулся с подобной проблемой, долго сидел и нашел предположительную причину. OnClick тут не при чем, все дело в специфике работы самого RecyclerView: при инициализации адаптер **один раз** создает **определенное** количество экземпляров ViewHolder в зависимости от размера экрана устройства. Они служат контейнерами для макетов элементов. Макет привязывается к холдеру только **один раз** в onCreateViewHolder() и принадлежит ему на протяжении всего существования. При прокрутке RecyclerView **вторично** использует ушедший с экрана холдер и его макет для отображения данных очередного элемента, используя onBindViewHolder(). Таким образом, *изменив макет одного из холдеров, при прокрутке можно встретить **этот же** холдер с его измененным макетом, только с другой позицией и другими данными.* Надеюсь, это окажется полезным для очередных первопроходцев.

Comment: Это не предположительная причина, а давно известный (и указанный в офф.документации, не надо было так долго сидеть и думать самому) факт - список переиспользует созданные айтемы (о чем говорит даже его название) и в текущюю видимую позицию вполне может попасть айтем, который "ушел" за экран - в этом принцип действия и оптимизация вывода в список и так и было задумано. Само происходящее в списке вы поняли правильно.

Comment: Факт может и известный, но, очевидно, не всем. Исходя из самого вопроса и отсутствия за полгода вразумительных ответов похоже, что документация не всем позволяет сразу, полностью и однозначно осознать все эти нюансы (особенно это касается делетантов вроде меня). Долго сидеть и думать самому - это нормально. Спасибо за комментарий.

Comment: Дело в том, что вопрос по переиспользованию айтемов ListView и RecyclerView, а также сопутствующим этому проблемам, задается здесь с завидной регулярностью, по нескольку раз каждый месяц (только я отвечал на похожие несколько раз, [например](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/592210/177345) или [вот](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460790/177345)) и при небольшом желании достаточно подробный ответ найти вполне возможно. Отсутствие описания происходящего в списках именно в этом вопросе не показатель, что тема не раскрыта.

Comment: Думать это очень хорошо, я согласен. То, что вы сами поняли механизм действия, тоже просто великолепно (правда по факту он намного сложней, но суть правильная), но например, у меня нет столько свободного времени, чтобы несколько дней самостоятельно разбираться, что же там может происходить - приходится форсировать и искать более быстрые пути к знаниям, офф.доки первое такое место, начинать изучение проблемы лучше все же именно оттуда.

Comment: Вы правы. Совершать работу, которой можно избежать - это преступление. К сожалению, как было сказано,  информация описанная в документации оказалась для меня не до конца понятной. В результате я пришёл к подобного рода проблеме. Отсутствие ответов заставило меня подойти к проблеме традиционным образом. Не несколько дней, но часов 5 я точно убил. Жаль конечно, что поделать.

Answer (score 2):

Вам не надо менять бэкграунд при нажатии. Он не сохранится. @Дмитрий Титов в своем ответе безупречно назвал причину этому. Что вам надо сделать? Завести массив и при нажатии менять в нем значения. А в `onBindViewHolder` в зависимости от этих значений ставить цвет. Кстати, на каждый `if` должен быть `else`. Гляньте на код. Делайте так всегда и запомните - просто так поменять что-то у элемента списка не получится

```
public class CalculatorHorizontalAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CalculatorHorizontalAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
private Course[] courseArray;
private boolean[] checks;
//это массив. в нем будем хранить true если фон изменен и false если нет
//по умолчанию все false это то что нам надо

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements OnClickListener
{

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition()); //обновляем. да, так надо, не знаю почему
        checks[getAdapterPosition()] = true; //меняем значение в массиве по позиции нажатого айтема
        notifyItemChanged(getAdapterPosition()); //еще раз после замены
    }

    public TextView ShortTv;
    public TextView LongTv;
    public TextView Long2Tv;
    public LinearLayout holderLayout;


    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        ShortTv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_calculator_currency_short_tv);
        holderLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.item_calculator_currency_ll);
        holderLayout.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
}
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
        .inflate(R.layout.item_calculator_currency, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    if (courseArray[position].currencyBuy != null)
        holder.ShortTv.setText(setOfCourses.get(position));
        //если значение в массиве true то ставим другой цвет
        if(checks[position]) holder.holderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#0f67c0")); 
        //иначе ставим цвет по умолчанию. я думаю у вас белый
        else holder.holderLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return courseArray.length;
}
public CalculatorHorizontalAdapter(Course[] courseArray) {
    this.courseArray = courseArray;
}
public CalculatorHorizontalAdapter() {

}
public void setCourseArray(Course[] courseArray) {
    this.courseArray = courseArray;
}
}
```

Comment: Ничего не изменилось( Так же при нажатии меняется фон у нескольких элементов, а не у того, на который нажал (

Comment: @Igor, обновил ответ

Answer (score 1):

*Элемент на который вы вешаете listener:*

```
LinearLayout holderLayout;
```

*Элемент которому вы кастуете цвет:*

```
LinearLayout holderLayout;
```

Comment: Да, т.е. на тот же элемент. Это не корректно?