# Проблема с изменением элемента RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `Fragment`. Есть в нем `RecyclerView` прикрепленный снизу. Суть в том, что по задумке самый первый элемент должен занимать чуть больше места чем остальные. Его я увеличиваю в `ViewHolder` самого адаптера при отрисовке следующим образом:

```
public class myAdapter {
...
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        WeatherForDay weather = mWeathersList.get(position);

        holder.mDayTextView.setText(weather.getDay());
        //todo update iconManager
        //need icon manager, with input -> String, output ->(R.drawable.icon) int
        holder.mIconImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.testicon1);
        holder.mTempTextView.setText(weather.getTmp());

        if (position == 0) {
            if (isFirstBind) {
                Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "is first bind and first position");
                holder.setBig();
                isFirstBind = false;
            }
        }
    }
...
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { ...
    public void setBig() {
                LinearLayout.LayoutParams param = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) mRoundLayout.getLayoutParams();
                int newHeight = (int) (param.height * 1.2f);
                int newWidth = (int) (param.height * 1.2f);
                param.height = newHeight;
                param.width = newWidth;
                mRoundLayout.setLayoutParams(param);
                mRoundLayout.setBackgroundDrawable(createBigShape(newHeight));
            }

            private Drawable createBigShape(int newHW) {
                GradientDrawable shape = new GradientDrawable();
                shape.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
                shape.setCornerRadii(new float[]{newHW, newHW, newHW, newHW, newHW, newHW, newHW, newHW});
                shape.setColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.weryDark));
                shape.setStroke(1, mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.weryDark));
                return shape;
            }
    ...
}
```

}
Каким образом заставить выравниваться элементы не по верхнему краю, а по нижнему?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Так же возникает проблема в том что N-ный элемент тоже каким то образом отрисовывается "большим" (на одном устройстве с большим экраном N = 13, на малом экране N = 8)

P.S.2 Может есть какой то более оптимальный способ изменить какой либо элемент `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить метод `getItemViewType()` адаптера и для `position = 0` выводить один тип разметки, для прочих позиций - другой.

Смотрите [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/470214/177345) для подробностей реализации.

Дополнения из комментариев, про повторение больших айтемов через определенное количество позиций:

`RecyclerView` переиспользует айтемы в целях оптимизации (айтемы, исчезающие cверху, появляются cнизу и изменяется в них только то, что явно указано в `onBindViewHolder()`), а то, что явно не устанавливается при биндинге в айтем, остается от прошлого айтема.
У вас при биндинге обрабатывается только позиция = 0, прочие позиции не определены, поэтому, когда доходит очередь до переиспользования первого айтема (например, в 8-ой позиции), в нем остается все так же, как и было (увеличеное изображение), так как для позиции, отличной от 0 явно не указано, какой вид использовать, поэтому у вас повторяется каждый N-ый элемент.

Вы можете либо принудительно устанавливать состояние для каждого айтема по позиции (а не только для большого вида)- большой или маленький, но поскольку у вас еще айтемы разного вида, логичнее использовать инструмент адаптера, специально предназначенный для этого - переопределение метода `getItemViewType()` - при переопределении метода адаптера `getItemViewType()` адаптер не переиспользует айтемы из разных типов между собой, поэтому это решение так же решит проблему повторов большого вида.

Comment: а чем это решение будет отличаться от того что я использовал? Я же работаю с тем же itemType, просто изменяю его параметры при определенном условии. Так же мне кажется очень странным что по логам сообщение Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "is first bind and first position"); отображается таки один раз - а item'a два

Comment: хотя кажежтся я начинаю понимать что разница все таки наверное есть. На английском so это дело обзывают header'om для recyclerview

Comment: @abbath0767 RecyclerView переиспользует айтемы в целях оптимизации (айтемы, исчезающие cверху, появляются cнизу и изменяется в них только то, что явно указано в `onBindViewHolder()`) , поэтому у вас повторяется каждый N-ый элемент. Вы можете либо принудительно устанавливать  состояние **для каждого айтема** - большой или маленький, но поскольку у вас еще айтемы разного вида, логичнее использовать инструмент адаптера, специально предназначенный для этого. getItemViewType()  не только для хидера, а для любых случаев, когда в одном списке необходимы айтемы разного вида, они могут и чередоваться.

Comment: @paviloff я может не правильно понял - но у меня айтем одного вида. Просто один из них должен менять размер некоторых внутренних объектов. Но он все равно остается одним и тем же. Или одни и те же айтемы с разными LayoutParams уже считаются разными?

Comment: @paviloff Сделал как вы посоветовали. Проблема пропала. Но я все равно так и и не понял. Что же все таки изменилось в структуре.

Comment: @abbath0767 айтемы переиспользуются, то, что явно не устанавливается при биндинге в айтем остается от прошлого айтема. У вас при биндинге обрабатывается только позиция = 0, прочие позиции не определены, поэтому, когда доходит очередь до переиспользования первого айтема (например, в 8-ой позиции), в нем остается все так же, как и было (увеличеное изображение), так как для позиции, отличной от 0 явно не указано, какой вид использовать. При переопределении метода адаптера `getItemViewType()` адаптер не переиспользует айтемы из разных типов между собой.

Comment: @paviloff благодарю за разъяснение про переиспользование.

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему костыльным, на мой взгляд методом. В `xml` добавил фиксированный размер высоты, который равен `mRoundLayout` * 1.2 (то есть что бы при увеличении точно умещался) + еще 20 dp для запаса под `TextView` и добавил bottom в `android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"` корневого элемента `item.xml`.

Правда почему еще один элемент становится "Большим" я так и не разобрался