# Как сохранить и восстановить состояние ячейки RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

Имеется `RecyclerView` вида:

```
Header
EditText
Switch
Spinner
...
Header
EditText
Switch
Spinner
...
```

Список достаточно большой, в нем есть различные элементы у которых можно менять состояние.

**Проблема:** если ввести значение в EditText, а затем проскролить его за экран и опять вернуться к нему, то введенное значение исчезнет.

**Вопрос:** как можно сохранять и восстанавливать состояние ячеек при переиспользовании?

Проблема исчезает если использовать `ScrollView` вместо `RecyclerView`, но нужна возможность динамического удаления добавления ячеек.

Comment: сохранение [из EditText](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460790/177345). Сохранение [из CheckBox](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/507146/177345) - тот же алгоритм для Switch, например и Spinner, только запоминать текущюю позицию

Comment: @pavlofff ваше решение подходит для статических списков, когда позиция айтема не меняется. Если список динамический - то это не будет работать, см ответ ниже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 Вариант:** сохранять состояние ячейки когда будет вызван метод `onViewRecycled(ViewHoder viewHolder)` у адаптера:

```
SparseArray<Object> states = new SparseArray();

public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (holder instanceof EditViewHolder) {
        String text = (String)states.get(holder.getAdapterPosition());
        ((EditViewHoder)holder).getEditText().setText(text);
    }
    //...
}

public void onViewRecycled(ViewHolder holder) {
    if(holder instanceof EditViewHoder) {
        String text = ((EditViewHoder)holder).getEditText().getText();
        states.put(position, text);
    }
    //...
    super.onViewRecycled(holder);
}
```

Такое решение подходит только для статических списков - если у вас поменяется порядок или удалится ячейка - все сломается.

---

**2 Вариант:** Воспользоваться готовым решением, например [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter)

для каждой ячейки необходимо реализовать специальный класс `ViewState`:

```
public class EditViewState implements ViewState<ViewHolder> {

    private final String mEnteredText;

    public EditViewState(ViewHolder holder) {
        EditText editText = holder.getViewFinder().find(R.id.your_edit_text);
        mEnteredText = editText.getText().toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void restore(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder) {
        holder.getViewFinder().setText(R.id.your_edit_text, mEnteredText);
    }
}
```

Более подробно можно найти в документации в разделе [ViewStates](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/wiki/Quick-start-with-ViewState)

Данная библиотека умеет работать с динамическими списками, при изменении порядка ячеек состояния не теряются и корректно восстанавливаются

Comment: Первый вариант не верный. Второй вариант вообще не про то.

Comment: @YuraIvanov как не про то, если я отвечал на свой вопрос?)))

Comment: Состояние и данные суть разные вещи. Если вы меняете данные в edittext, то меняйте данные и вызывайте notifyitemchanged. А состояние - это то, что к данным не имеет отношения, например, selected, expanded, и проч. Ваш вопрос о неправильном использовании патерна viewholder, а не о состояниях.

Comment: @YuraIvanov мой вопрос о сохранении состояния ячейки, c `EditText` 
 не все так просто, в каких-то случаях это данные, например когда бизнеслогика говорит отобразить это, а в каких то случаях это состояние, когда пользователь поменял данные, но еще не сохранил. Читайте внимательно вопрос и ответ к нему. Если есть другие решения - предлагайте отдельным ответом, этот холивар предлагаю закрыть.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/31844373/1023786 вот правильный ответ про edittext.

Comment: @YuraIvanov и чем он правильнее чем описано выше? В примере выше сохранение состояния происходит когда система вызывает `onViewRecycled`. Следуя из [документации](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onViewRecycled(VH)) как раз то что нужно. В вашем примере сохранение состояния происходит каждый раз как меняется текст - лишние операции. Не понимаю почему вы в первом комментарии сказали что первый вариант не верный. Если не придераться - то оба варианта рабочие, если думать об оптимизации, то вариант предложенный мной выше предпочтительнее.

Comment: Вы считаете, что если onViewRecycled не вызовется (не было скролинга) и изменения в edittext'е нигде не сохранятся - это нормальное поведение программы?

Comment: в рамках этого вопроса - да, так как речь идет именно о состоянии. Если говорить про данные и дальнейшую их передачу - то нужно сохранять и сохранять не в адаптере.