# Как сохранять EditText в строках RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Имею RecyclerView, в каждой строчке которого есть EditText. Как сохранять все значения, введенные в эти EditText`s, при переходе в другую активность, сворачивании и закрытии приложения? Спасибо!

**MainActivity**

````
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    RecyclerView.Adapter gAdapter;
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    public static List<ListCigarets> listUtilsPrint;

    RequestQueue rw;

    String request_url = "http://www.json-generator.com";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_newspaper);

        rw = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewNewspaper);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        listUtilsPrint = new ArrayList<>();

        sendRequest();
    }

    public void sendRequest() {
        JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, request_url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                    ListCigarets listPrint = new ListCigarets();
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);

                        listPrint.setName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                        listPrint.setBarcode(jsonObject.getString("barcode"));
                        listPrint.setPrice(jsonObject.getString("price"));

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    listUtilsPrint.add(listPrint);
                }
                gAdapter = new CustomRecyclerAdapter(NewspaperActivity.this, listUtilsPrint);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(gAdapter);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.i("Volley Error: ", String.valueOf(error));
            }


        });
        rw.add(jsonArrayRequest);```
````

**Adapter**

```
private Context context;
public static List<ListCigarets> listCigarets;
public static int count;

public CustomRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List listCigarets) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listCigarets = listCigarets;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_activity, parent, false);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);
    return viewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    final ListCigarets product = listCigarets.get(position);

    holder.itemView.setTag(listCigarets.get(position));

    ListCigarets pu = listCigarets.get(position);

    holder.gName.setText(pu.getName());
    holder.gBarcode.setText(pu.getBarcode());
    holder.gPrice.setText(pu.getPrice());

    holder.quantity.setText(formatValue(product.getCount(), product.getUnit()));

    holder.plus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count = product.getCount() + 1;
            product.setCount(count);
            holder.quantity.setText(formatValue(count, product.getUnit()));
        }
    });
    holder.minus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            count = product.getCount() - 1;
            if(count < 0) count = 0;
            product.setCount(count);
            holder.quantity.setText(formatValue(count, product.getUnit()));
        }
    });

}

private String formatValue(int count, String unit) {
    return String.valueOf(count);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listCigarets.size();
}

public void filterList(ArrayList<ListCigarets> filteredList) {
    listCigarets = filteredList;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView gName;
    public TextView gBarcode;
    public TextView gPrice;
    public ImageButton plus;
    public ImageButton minus;
    public EditText quantity;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        gName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameCart);
        gBarcode = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.barcodeCart);
        gPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceCart);
        quantity = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.quantity);
        plus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.plus);
        minus = (ImageButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.minus);

    }
}
```

```
 [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZwd7.png
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/460790/177345

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите, когда вы просто листаете список в этот момент ваш ViewHolder уже перезатирает скрытые EditText-ы т.к. RecyclerView переиспользует ViewHolder-ы.

Исходя из этого вам вероятно нужно хранить в вашем RecyclerView эти строки.
Я бы создал какую-нибудь `Map<Int, String>` где **key** - это позиция, а **value** - ваша строка. При бинде вашего ViewHolder-а вы будете смотреть на эту мапу, если под ключем равным позиции уже есть какое-то значение - вы заполняете им ваш EditText, иначе - оставляете пустым.

Правда тут нужно следить за тем, что если в вашем RecyclerView могут добавляться новые элементы или изменяться позиции старых, вам нужно и менять значения по ключам измененных позиций.